# Simple regex not

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a way to write the following in only one `preg_replace`

```
$url = "stackoverflow";
  if(!preg_match('/apple/',$url)){
    $url = $url.".apple.com";
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want urls such as `stackoverflow.com.apple.com` ?

Comment: lets say url = "stackoverflow" without the TLD

Comment: Err your question doesn't really make sense. Will the string always end with apple? if not then you can't use regex to append to a string.

Comment: so basically you want any $url that doesn't already contain the word apple, to now be appended with ".apple.com"?

Comment: YES!! why is that so cray cray? lol

Comment: TLD = top level domain. @ThomasReggi Are you looking for something like `preg_replace('/apple/', '$1.apple.com', $string)` ?

Comment: Because the input URL could be anything, in which case the output URL will be bogus. as in my example.

Comment: @fersch you missed the `!preg_match`

Comment: @ean5533 it means "crazy" - @ThomasReggi the code looks like it should work. Did you echo `$url` to see the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'something';
echo preg_replace('/^(?:(?!apple).)*$/is', '$0.apple.com', $str);
```

ps: modifiers `is` might be useful.

`(?: )*` makes non-capturing pattern. It matches zero or more instances of a `(?!apple)`. Which is anything except of `apple` and `$0` tells to take the whole string when pattern is matched. Example suggested above is not the same, because it will match anything when the string does not start with `apple` as `?!apple` condition is applied only once, at the beginning of the string.

Comment: The lookahead can be put outside of the `(.)*` bracket (since the match is anchored), preventing unnecessary string scanning: `'/^(?!apple).*$/i`.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee     try your regexp - it won't work as requested

Comment: @Josh  (?: )* makes non-capturing pattern. It matches zero or more instances of a (?!apple). Which is anything except of `apple` and $0 tells to take the whole string when pattern is matched. Example suggested above is not the same, because it will match anything when the string does not start with `apple` as ?!apple condition is applied only once, at the beginning of the string.